# Cannot change current password in android 7

Tags: android-7.0-nougat, securityexception, device-admin, reset-password, device-policy-manager

My app has device administration power. When I tried to update the current password in android 7, This "java.lang.SecurityException: Admin cannot change current password" exception is coming. It's working in android 6. Please tell me How can I reset my password in nougat.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include your device admin metadata XML resource, your manifest entry referring to that metadata, your Java code confirming that you are an active device admin and trying to change the password, and the complete Java stack trace of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google has changed the ability of device admin apps. I don't fully understand why. I know it could be used by hackers, but that's why screen lock is a separate permissions set you have to enable.

> We’ve reduced the power of device admin applications so they can no longer change your lockscreen if you have a lockscreen set, and device admin will no longer be notified of impending disable via onDisableRequested().These were tactics used by some ransomware to gain control of a
>   device.

Here's the full link https://blog.google/topics/connected-workspaces/keeping-android-safe-security-enhancements-nougat/